# UIButton inside custom UIView class not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uibutton

I know this question has been asked lots of times but none of solutions worked for me.

I have a custom UIView class which I use for displaying alert message. I added UIButton to close the view. However, nothing happens when I tab it.

```
import UIKit
public class Alert: UIView {

    public var image: UIImage?
public var title: String?
public var message: String?
public var closeButtonText: String?

public var dialogBackgroundColor: UIColor = .white
public var dialogTitleTextColor: UIColor = .black
public var dialogMessageTextColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)
public var dialogImageColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.72, blue:0.35, alpha:1.0)
public var overlayColor: UIColor = .black
public var overlayOpacity: CGFloat = 0.66

public var paddingSingleTextOnly: CGFloat = 8
public var paddingTopAndBottom: CGFloat = 24
public var paddingFromSides: CGFloat = 8
public var seperatorHeight: CGFloat = 6

private var height: CGFloat = 0
private var width: CGFloat = 0
private var maxSize: CGSize = CGSize()
private let marginFromSides: CGFloat = 80

public lazy var imageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)

public var overlay = false
public var blurOverlay = true

//animation duration
public var duration = 0.33

private var onComplete: (() ->  Void)?

@objc public var titleFont: UIFont =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
@objc public var messageFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)


private lazy var backgroundView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.alpha = 0
    return view
}()

public let dialogView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.alpha = 0
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    return view
}()

private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return view
}()

public lazy var closeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    return button
}()

private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()

private lazy var messageLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()

@objc func closeButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
    dismiss()
}

private func calculations() {
    height += paddingTopAndBottom
    maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.width - marginFromSides * 2, height: frame.height - marginFromSides)
}

public convenience init(title:String, message: String, image:UIImage) {
    self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.title = title
    self.message = message
    self.image = image
}

public convenience init(title:String, image:UIImage) {
    self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.title = title
    self.image = image
}

public convenience init(title: String, message: String) {
    self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.title = title
    self.message = message
}

public convenience init(message: String) {
    self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    paddingTopAndBottom = paddingSingleTextOnly
    paddingFromSides = paddingSingleTextOnly * 2
    self.message = message
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func createOverlay() {
    backgroundView.frame = frame
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = overlayColor
    backgroundView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(backgroundView)
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        window.addSubview(backgroundView)
    } else if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
        window.view.addSubview(self)
    }
}

private func createBlurOverlay() {
    backgroundView.frame = frame
    //Blur Effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = frame
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    backgroundView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    addSubview(backgroundView)
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        window.addSubview(backgroundView)
    } else if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
        window.view.addSubview(self)
    }
}

private func createTitle(title: String) {
    titleLabel.font = titleFont
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.frame.origin.y = height + 2
    let titleLabelSize = titleLabel.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
    handleSize(size: titleLabelSize)
    titleLabel.frame.size = titleLabelSize
    titleLabel.textColor = self.dialogTitleTextColor
    dialogView.addSubview(titleLabel)
}

private func createMessage(message: String) {
    messageLabel.font = messageFont
    messageLabel.text = message
    messageLabel.frame.origin.y = height
    let messageLabelSize = messageLabel.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
    messageLabel.frame.size = messageLabelSize
    messageLabel.textColor = self.dialogMessageTextColor
    handleSize(size: messageLabelSize)
    dialogView.addSubview(messageLabel)
}


private func createImage(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.frame.origin.y = height
    imageView.frame.size = imageSize
    imageView.tintColor = self.dialogImageColor
    handleSize(size: imageSize)
    dialogView.addSubview(imageView)
}

private func createButton(){
    closeButton.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
    closeButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    closeButton.frame.origin.y = height + 20
    let closeButtonSize = CGSize(width: width - 60, height: 60)
    closeButton.frame.size = closeButtonSize
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    closeButton.backgroundColor = Color.NavigationBar.tintColor
    closeButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    handleSize(size: closeButtonSize)
    dialogView.addSubview(closeButton)
}

private func createDialog() {
    centerAll()
    height += paddingTopAndBottom
    dialogView.frame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    dialogView.backgroundColor = self.dialogBackgroundColor
    dialogView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(dialogView)
    self.dialogView.center = self.center
    self.dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.15, y: 1.15)
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        window.addSubview(dialogView)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.view.addSubview(self)
        window.view.addSubview(self)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

private func centerAll() {
    if ((messageLabel.text) != nil) {
        messageLabel.frame.origin.x = (width - messageLabel.frame.width) / 2
    }

    if ((titleLabel.text) != nil) {
        titleLabel.frame.origin.x = (width - titleLabel.frame.width) / 2
    }

    if ((imageView.image) != nil) {
        imageView.frame.origin.x = (width - imageView.frame.width) / 2
    }
    closeButton.frame.origin.x = (width - closeButton.frame.width) / 2

}

private func handleSize(size: CGSize) {
    if width < size.width + paddingFromSides * 2 {
        width = size.width + paddingFromSides * 2
    }
    if paddingTopAndBottom != paddingSingleTextOnly {
        height += seperatorHeight
    }
    height += size.height
}

private func showAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        if self.overlay {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = self.overlayOpacity
            self.dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        }
        self.dialogView.alpha = 1
    })

}
public func show() {
    if let complete = onComplete {
        self.onComplete = complete
    }
    calculations()

    if self.overlay {
        if blurOverlay {
            createBlurOverlay()
        } else {
            createOverlay()
        }
    }

    if let img = image {
        createImage(image: img)
    }
    if let title = title {
        createTitle(title: title)
    }
    if let message = message {
        createMessage(message: message)
    }
    createButton()
    createDialog()

    showAnimation()

}

public func dismiss(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        if self.overlay {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
        }
        self.dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.15, y: 1.15)
        self.dialogView.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { (completed) in
        self.dialogView.removeFromSuperview()
        if (self.overlay)
        {
            self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.removeFromSuperview()
        if let completionHandler = self.onComplete {
            completionHandler()
        }
    })
}
}
```

How I create the alert;

```
let alert = Alert(title: "hata",message: "hata mesajı ekrana basıldı", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "error"))
alert.show()
```

If I declare target inside UIViewController (Where I create this UIView) as

```
Alert.closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped(sender:), for: .touchUPInside)
```

and create function inside UIViewController It is working. I can't figure out why It doesn't work when in custom class.

So my question is that how can close the alert view when tabbed the button?

I tried below solution but didn't work for me;

[UIButton target action inside custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465455/uibutton-target-action-inside-custom-class)

Comment: Your code isn't really showing what's going on... Where are you adding the button to a view? How are you showing the view? Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DonMag I edited my code. Can you please check? Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more thorough. I pasted your code into a swift file and there are dozens of errors (unresolved identifiers, etc). Strip your code down to the basics to start - only what you need to show your view and add the button. Once you get your button / dismiss working, *then* you can add in everything else.

Comment: I add the whole code. This one should work. @DonMag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these lines are inside a function - such as due to a button tap:

```
@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = Alert(title: "hata",message: "hata mesajı ekrana basıldı", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "error"))
    alert.show()
}
```

You are creating an instance of your `Alert` class, calling the `.show()` function inside it, and then it goes out of scope.

So, as soon as that function exists, `alert` no longer exists, and no code inside it can run.

You need to have a class-level variable to hold onto it while it is displayed:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var alert: Alert?

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        alert = Alert(title: "hata",message: "hata mesajı ekrana basıldı", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "error"))
        alert?.show()
    }

}
```

Here is a demonstration of the "Wrong Way" and the "Right Way" to handle your `Alert` view: https://github.com/DonMag/EmreTest

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I want to achieve. I have UIButton inside Alert view and that button closes the alert view. So I don't wanna call show() inside button tap function. Thank you :)

Comment: No... this is the code in your VIewController as you posted in your question `How I create the alert;`. Those two lines of code are being called from *somewhere* in that ViewController. Wherever you are calling it from, the object created by `let alert = Alert(...)` is going out of scope when that code function/method/block finishes, and your new object goes away. The *view* remains on the screen, but the *code* behind it is gone.

Comment: @EmreÖnder - see the edit to my answer. Try it yourself... create a new ViewController, add a button, and use the above code to test it.

Comment: I edit my question to be more clear. What am I asking was how can I close the alert view, not to open it.

Comment: @EmreÖnder - if you *try* my answer, you will see that the button in your "alert view" ***does*** now close the view. The problem is that when you instantiate the `Alert` class, and you exit whatever function that line of code is in, you also ***DESTROY*** that class, so the button code cannot run - it no longer exists! Just try doing what I showed you, and you will see.

Comment: @EmreÖnder -- here, I put it up as an example project for you: https://github.com/DonMag/EmreTest

Comment: You saved the day! I got it now. Thank you! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167418/discussion-between-emre-onder-and-donmag).

Answer (score -1):

Look this code

1- Call IBAction inside UIView Class

```
import UIKit

public class Alert: UIView {

    public lazy var closeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
        return button
    }()

    func createDialog() {
          closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(closeButton)
    }

    @objc func closeButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
        print("Call   1")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let alert = Alert(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        alert.createDialog()

        self.view.addSubview(alert)
    }

}
```

2- Call IBAction inside UIViewController Class

```
import UIKit

public class Alert: UIView {

    public lazy var closeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
        return button
    }()

    func createDialog() {
        //  closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(closeButton)
    }

    @objc func closeButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
        print("Call   1")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let alert = Alert(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        alert.createDialog()
        alert.closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeButtonTappedController(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(alert)
    }

    @IBAction func closeButtonTappedController(_ sender:UIButton){
        print("Call   2")

    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh... **Please** do not post screen-shots of code.

Comment: It has been modified but i'm add screen to show up output